# C# Left Join with Linq not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database where some ForeignKeys can be NULL. So I made for selecting data a left-join like I found it in some other posts.

```
var query =
            from z in context.zeichnungen
            join f in context.fremdschlüssel.DefaultIfEmpty() on z.ZeichnungID equals f.ZeichnungID
            join t in context.tags.DefaultIfEmpty() on f.TagID equals t.TagID into tz
            from t in tz.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join s in context.status.DefaultIfEmpty() on z.StatusID equals s.StatusID into sz
            from s in sz.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join a in context.artikelbezeichnungen.DefaultIfEmpty() on z.ArtikelbezeichnungID equals a.ArtikelbzeichnungID into az
            from a in az.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join b in context.sammellbemerkungen on z.SammelberkungID equals b.SammelbemerkungID
            join m in context.sachmerkmale on z.SachmerkmalID equals m.SachmerkmalID into mz
            from m in mz.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where (zeichnungsnummer == "" || z.Zeichnungsnummer.Contains(zeichnungsnummer)) &&
            (index == "" || index == z.Index) && (tag == "" || t.Tag_Text == tag) &&
            (artikelbezeichnung == "" || artikelbezeichnung == a.Artikelbezeichnung) &&
            (status == "" || status == s.Status_Bezeichnung) && (mmsSachmerkmal == "" || mmsSachmerkmal == m.Sachmerkmal) &&
            (doktyp == "" || doktyp == z.Dokumententyp) && (dateiendung == "" || dateiendung == z.Dateiendung) &&
            (z.Datum >= startDate.Date && z.Datum <= endDate.Date) && (status == "" || status == s.Status_Bezeichnung)
            select new
            {
                f,
                z,
                t,
                s,
                a,
                b,
                m
            };
```

But the select only shows data when the foreign keys are filled. Can someone explain what I did wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is the Select from Debug.

> FROM `zeichnungen` AS `Extent1` 
>   INNER JOIN `fremdschlüssel` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ZeichnungID` = `Extent2`.`ZeichnungID`
>   INNER JOIN `tags` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent2`.`TagID` = `Extent3`.`TagID`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `status` AS `Extent4` ON `Extent1`.`StatusID` = `Extent4`.`StatusID`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `artikelbezeichnungen` AS `Extent5` ON `Extent1`.`ArtikelbezeichnungID` = `Extent5`.`ArtikelbzeichnungID`
>   INNER JOIN `sammellbemerkungen` AS `Extent6` ON `Extent1`.`SammelberkungID` = `Extent6`.`SammelbemerkungID`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `sachmerkmale` AS `Extent7` ON `Extent1`.`SachmerkmalID` = `Extent7`.`SachmerkmalID`

Comment: Your query is a bit complex to answer your question, try looking at the generated sql query. If you are using EF in context constructor you can attach logging:  `Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);`; Inspect if all required left joins are there.

Comment: "Can someone explain what I did wrong?" To be honest.. No. It would take too much time for me. But I would suggest to start with the first join separately and if you get this right add the next one and so on.

Comment: @Rafal thanks for the tipp. I updated it with the real select.